# iframe - responded with full html

Tags: php, html, iframe

I am using a  block to sends a request to an external host and get a response. In the response I get a full html page.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
// My Content
</body>
</html>
```

I am only returning "My Content" as the response. But it responsed with full HTML like above.

Is there a way, only to response with "My Content"?

This is my  block

```
<iframe frameborder="no" height="200px" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no" src="myServicePoint.php" title="MyTitle" width="200px"></iframe>
```

Please help on me on this.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't looking at the response. You are looking at the page in a DOM inspector.

The browser is automatically inserting the HTML elements which either have optional start / end tags or which are required and are being added for error recovery purposes.

There is no way to stop the browser doing this.

You should fix the page at the URL you are requesting so it is a valid HTML document.